# Playing an animation in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I've loaded some images in a list and I'm trying to play them through a loop when called but the images don't seem to load. It's meant to be for a transition period. Here's a sample of my code:

```
images = [".\\ANIM\\trans_00001.png",".\\ANIM\\trans_00002.png",".\\ANIM\\trans_00003.png"]

playAnimation=True
counter=0

if playAnimation:
     pygame.image.load(images[counter])
     counter=(counter+1)%len(images)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so people can help you.

Comment: Also, take a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) returns a `pygame.Surface` object which you have to assign to a variable or put it into a list or other data structure if you want to use it later.

I recommend loading the images when you define the `images` list because it's inefficient to load them from the hard disk repeatedly.

```
images = [
    pygame.image.load(".\\ANIM\\trans_00001.png"),
    pygame.image.load(".\\ANIM\\trans_00002.png"),
    pygame.image.load(".\\ANIM\\trans_00003.png"),
    ]
```

Then access the current image in this way:

```
current_image = images[counter]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the only problem, because your code example is incomplete and your problem description is too short.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
while playAnimation:
```

instead of

```
if playAnimation:
```